# Can we assume the `http://` for an openID URL?

Tags: feature-request, login, openid

Under the old login system I could type my.openiddomain.com and then login to my own openid server.

Now, however, I get the error, "Please enter a URL" when I attempt this.  This is very inconvenient on tablets and phones.

Is there a reason the new system no longer assumes HTTP? If the new system cannot be adapted to not require the `http://` prefix, can the textbox be pre-populated with it?

Ideally the system would accept a URL without any prefix and try HTTPS and then HTTP before erroring out and requesting a full URL.

Comment: The OpenID spec requires the server to assume http if no scheme is provided (which seems kind of bad, but I digress), although I guess you could argue this is just a form validation issue.